# PHP Minutes in month

Tags: php, time

I need to be able to find the number of minutes passed in the current month so far. So from midnight of the first of the month until now.

How could I do this? So for example, 1AM on the first of the month would be give me 60 minutes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$time = time();
$minutes = ($time-strtotime(date('Y-m-00', $time)))/60;
```

As of now `$minutes === 15477.1`

Answer (score 2):

```
$seconds = time() - strtotime('2011-01-01 00:00:00');
$minutes = $seconds / 60;
```

To elaborate a bit more:

This is some simple manipulation of a unix timestamp (number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970).  So you take the current timestamp and subtract what the timestamp would have been on the first of the month.  This gives you total seconds that have elapsed this month. If you divide by 60, you get total minutes that have elapsed this month.

Comment: bad example, you should use `ceil` at least, and OP is asking the current month